# Mock in unit test is not working. Select into database is working now

Tags: java, spring, rest, unit-testing, mockito

I have a service class, that executes user's request:

```
public class UnitServiceImpl extends HttpRequestServiceImpl implements UnitService {
    private final UnitRepository unitRepository;

    public UnitServiceImpl(UnitRepository unitRepository) {
        this.unitRepository = unitRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Unit addUnit(String unitName) {
        final Unit unit = new Unit();
        unit.setUnitName(unitName);
        return unitRepository.save(unit);
    }

    @Override
    public Unit getUnit(int id) {
        final Unit unit = unitRepository.findById(id);
        if (unit == null) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Unit is not found");
        }
        return unit;
    }

    @Override
    public Unit updateUnit(int id, String unitName) {
        final Unit unit = getUnit(id);
        unit.setUnitName(unitName);
        return unitRepository.save(unit);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<Unit> getAllUnits() {
        return unitRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Controller, that's use Service:

```
@RestController
public class UnitController {
    private final UnitService managementService;

    public UnitController(UnitService managementService) {
        this.managementService = managementService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/unit", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Iterable<Unit>> getAllUnits() {
        final Iterable<Unit> allUnits = managementService.getAllUnits();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(allUnits, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/unit", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Unit> addUnit(HttpServletRequest request) throws FieldsIsAbsentException {
        final String unitName = managementService.getParameter(request, "unit_name");

        final Unit unit = managementService.addUnit(unitName);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(unit, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/unit/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Unit> getUnitById(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        final Unit unit = managementService.getUnit(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(unit, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PutMapping(value = "/unit/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Unit> updateUnit(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable("id") int id) {
        final String unitName = managementService.getParameter(request, "unit_name");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(managementService.updateUnit(id, unitName), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
}
```

I created unit tests. They are mockito methods isn't working. All test methods doing request to database.   Test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationTestConfig.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class UnitControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    UnitService unitService;

    @Autowired
    private UnitController unitController;

    private final List<Unit> units = new ArrayList<>();

    @BeforeEach
    public void initUnits() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(unitController)
                .setControllerAdvice(new ExceptionHandlingController()).build();

        Unit unit = new Unit();
        unit.setUnitName("someUnit 1");
        unit.setId(1);
        units.add(unit);

        unit = new Unit();
        unit.setId(2);
        unit.setUnitName("Some unit 2");
        units.add(unit);
    }

    @Test
    void testGetAllUnits() throws Exception {
        when(this.unitService.getAllUnits()).thenReturn(units);
        mockMvc.perform(get("/unit"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }

    @Test
    void testUnitNotFound() throws Exception {
        int id = -1;
        given(this.unitService.getUnit(id)).willThrow(EntityNotFoundException.class);
        mockMvc.perform(get("/unit/" + id))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isNotFound())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }

    @Test
    void testUnitFound() throws Exception {
        int id = 5;
        Unit unitWithName = new Unit();
        unitWithName.setId(id);
        unitWithName.setUnitName("NameUnit");
        given(unitService.getUnit(id)).willReturn(unitWithName);
        mockMvc.perform(get("/unit/" + id).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value(id))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.unitName").value(unitWithName.getUnitName()));
    }

    @Test
    void testAddUnit() throws Exception {
        Unit unit = new Unit();
        unit.setId(1);
        unit.setUnitName("TestUnit");

        given(unitService.addUnit("TestUnit")).willReturn(unit);
        mockMvc.perform(post("/unit").param("unit_name", "TestUnit"))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.unitName").value(unit.getUnitName()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value(1));
    }
}
```

This code is trying to read or write to database. I've tried so many variants.
I've been trying to write tests for a few days.=( What is the error?

Comment: I would also like to know what is the error - could you show the stacktrace?

Comment: I haven't an exception. It just executes request to database now. For example, the last method, testAddUnit, inserts new Unit into database, but it must be fake insert.

Comment: you are using mocks and you are surprised that it doesnt insert anything? In general it is better to separate controller testing and jpa testing. In controller layer tests you just test the  controller, that if this request is done, then this response is returned. In JPA test (separate TestClass) use @DataJpaTest annotation and test your select/insert methods. If you want an integration test (testing a user story from the moment of click till the database insert and maybe more) you should use yet another test file without mocks.

Comment: I'm using mocks and I'm surprised that it do insert =)
I created tests like in that project: https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-petclinic-rest/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/rest/PetRestControllerTests.java

Comment: it must work because you are starting the whole Context with all the other annotations `@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationTestConfig.class)` - usually you just use `@MockMvcTest` I am guessing they did in the project like that because of spring security

Comment: Yeah, you are right! I've change annotations and it works now! But I have one problem with testAddUnit. Returning body is empty. Therefore it fails with an error "AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.unitName"". What is it could be wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t know, but you should post a new question explaining the new problem so somebody else can help u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed my test class onto next code and it works now:

```
@WebMvcTest(UnitController.class)
class UnitControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    UnitService unitService;

    private final List<Unit> units = new ArrayList<>();

    @BeforeEach
    public void initUnits() {
        Unit unit = new Unit();
        unit.setUnitName("someUnit 1");
        unit.setId(1);
        units.add(unit);

        unit = new Unit();
        unit.setId(2);
        unit.setUnitName("Some unit 2");
        units.add(unit);
    }

///test methods
```